# Problems with uploading resume on when applying for jobs on Careers 2.0

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs

Has anyone else experienced errors when attempting to upload their resume when applying for jobs on Careers 2.0?

I keep getting an error stating my resume can't be uploaded.

Comment: What type of file are you trying to upload?

Answer (score 1):

No repro. I just applied for my current job, uploading a PDF resume and everything else worked fine.

Any chance there's a problem with the file you're trying to upload?

[image]